# A element can be a set?

Tags: set-theory, well-orders

I am trying to prove that an arbitrary set $X$ is partial-ordered with respect to subset relation $\subset$ but I have some doubts. Indeed,

(i) $\forall x\in X$, $x\subset x$

(ii) $\forall x,y\in X$, if $x\subset y$ and $y\subset x$, then $x=y$

(iii) $\forall x,y,z\in X$, if $x\subset y$ and $y\subset z$, then $x\subset z$.

Is it correct to assume that $\forall x\in X$, $x$ is a subset? My answer is Yes only if $X$ is not empty by the foundation axiom. I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: "for every $x\in X$, $x$ is a subset" is incomplete/nonsensical. "subset" of **what**?

Comment: If $X=\emptyset$ then $1, 2,3$ all follows vacuously.

Comment: If $x\in\emptyset$ then $x \subset{\text{_}} $. To prove this statement false, you have to find a $x\in\emptyset$ sucht that ___.

Answer (score 3):

The empty set is a subset of itself. Indeed, the empty set is a subset of any set. This is proven as follows. Given a set $X$, suppose that $\varnothing\not\subset X$. This means that exists some object $x\in\varnothing$ such that $x\not\in X$, which is a contradiction, because the empty set has no elements. The existence of the empty set is assured by the *empty set axiom*.